# how to remove object from LIST<T>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

My List is

```
          public List<BaseHomePage.QueueListItem> QueueDataSource
         {
          get { return this._queueDataSource; }
          set { this._queueDataSource = value; }
         }
```

and i want to remove the object from the list,my code is

```
         for (int i = 0; i < _queueDataSource.Count; i++)
        {
            object queue = _queueDataSource[i];


            if (objQuery.BranchOutQueue)
            {
                this._queueDataSource.Remove(queue); //Here I want to getting erroe

            }
```

> Error : The best overload method match for `system.collections.Generic.List<baseHomePage.QueueListItem>.Remove(BaseHome.QueueList)` has some invalid arguments

Comment: Instead of object queue = _queueDataSource[i]; try BaseHomePage.QueueListItem = _queueDataSource[i];

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
object queue = _queueDataSource[i];
```

with

```
var queue = _queueDataSource[i];
```

or even

```
BaseHomePage.QueueListItem queue = _queueDataSource[i];
```

At the moment you're discarding the information that `queue` is a specific type of item, but you're only allowed to remove that specific type of item from the list.

Comment: The index should also be adjusted to account for the removal.

Comment: @GrantThomas Actually... unless `objQuery.BranchOutQueue` changes, he might as well just call `Clear` on the list :-s

Comment: I am getting this exception also: The best overload method match for'system.collections.Generic.List<baseHomePage.QueueListItem>.Remove(BaseHome.QueueList)'has some invalid arguments

Comment: @lakki Are you _sure_ that's the error message? The type inside `< >` and the type inside `( )` should match.